# JQuery dropdown menu addClass on Keydown down arrow

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to get the first link's background to change to red when the downarrow is hit. There is something wrong, it only changes red if you hold down the arrow key. It just flashes red once, then back to white. It is as if some event is occuring right after causing it to go back to default. I am still learning JQuery, so I suspect that is where the problem lies. I tried a bunch of different ideas but I can't figure this one out still. If anyone can spot my issue I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Here is my JQuery:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$(document).click(function() {
    $("#SearchResults").hide();
});

$("#SearchInput").keydown(function(e) {
if(e.which == 8) {
SearchText = $("#SearchInput").val().substring(0, $("#SearchInput").val().length-1);
} else if (e.keyCode == 40) { //down
var curr = $("#SearchResults").find("a.selected");
if (curr.length == 0) {
    curr = $("#SearchResults").find("a:first");
}

} else {    
SearchText = $("#SearchInput").val() + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
}


$('#SearchResults').load('/ajaxPHP/ajaxSearch.php',{ SearchInput: SearchText }, function() {
curr.addClass('selected');
});
$("#SearchResults").slideDown();

});
});
</script>

Here is my CSS
#SearchInput {   
width:340px; 
height:24px; 
margin-top:15px; 
border:none; 
padding-left:12px; 
padding-right:10px; 
color:#333;
-moz-border-radius:2px;
-webkit-border-radius:2px;
border-radius:2px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color:#fff; /* Fallback */
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 1px 1px #363636;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 1px 1px #363636;
box-shadow: inset 0 2px 1px 1px #363636;
}

#SearchResults {
float:left;    
position:fixed !important;
background: #fff;
border:1px solid #333;
display: none;

width: 360px;
z-index: 9999 !important;
top:40px;
max-height:420px;
color:#333;
margin-left:9px;
}

#SearchResults h1 {
display: block;
padding: 10px 5px 10px 15px;
font-size:13px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#333;
border-top:1px solid #999;
background: #eeeeee; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%, #cccccc 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#eeeeee), color-stop(100%,#cccccc)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#cccccc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

#SearchResults a {
z-index: 9999 !important; 
color: #333;
font-size:13px;
display: block;
padding: 15px 5px 15px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#SearchResults a:hover {
z-index: 9999 !important; 
color: #fff;
background: #999;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: why do you have ```if($("#SearchInput").val() == "") {
$("#SearchInput").val("");
}```

Comment: I'm not sure, I am modifying this code piece by piece I can't remember where I found it.

Comment: I just took it out, it was not necessary in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that your AJAX call:

```
$("#SearchResults").load("/ajaxPHP/ajaxSearch.php", { SearchInput: SearchText });
```

is replacing the content, and thus clearing the class you're applying.

Fortunately, there's a `complete` callback for the `$.load` method, so you should be able to do something like this:

```
$("#SearchResults").load("/ajaxPHP/ajaxSearch.php", { SearchInput: SearchText },
  function(response, status, xhr) {
    curr.addClass('selected');  
});
```

Comment: still broken, but thanks for the tip I agree I think the .load is the problem. I'll keep digging.

Comment: If someone can help me finish this project I will pay them over PayPal